# Can we extend Hoeffding's inequality to the case where $n$ itself is variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

> Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $a \leq X_i \leq b$. Define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Hoeffding's inequality states that with probability at least $1 - \delta$, $\left|\frac{S_n - \mathbb{E}(S_n)} n\right| \leq (b-a) \sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2n} \log\left(\frac{2}{\delta}\right)\right)}$.

I'm wondering how things change if $n$ itself is a random variable, i.e. $n$ is not constant. (*I know that $n$ is supposed to be constant in Hoeffding's inequality*).

Is there a variant I can use for the purpose of variable $n$, or is there any way to extend this itself?

Comment: Have you seen the proof of Hoeffding's inequality? Have you thought about how you could make things work if $n$ was random in that proof?

Comment: Furthermore, the first example of when $n$ is considered a random variable, is Wald's identities. Look those up, see how they are proved, find a common technique which you can apply here.